# ASP.Net Core Razor Ajax Request JSON value null

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I am using .Net Core razor for my application.

When I call the controller action from my Ajax, the value I pass comes null to the controller.

Here is my script:

```
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
var data = table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();
console.log(data);

var data_json = JSON.stringify({ 'data_json': data });
console.log(data_json);

        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateChart","Home")',
            data: data_json,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                myFunction(result);
                chart.render();
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

I simply get the values of selected checkboxes and convert them into JSON.

My Controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult UpdateChart(List<CheckBoxArray> data_json)
        {
            ChartRepository repository = new ChartRepository();
            string deviceSerialNo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber") != null ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber").ToString() : "1606008363";
            string query = repository.PrepSelectQuery("1", deviceSerialNo, "2021-03-04 10:04:55.544398", "2021-03-05 10:46:55.544398");
            GeneralObjects.ServiceResponse response = repository.GetChartData(query);

            TempData["AllData"] = response.This_Object;
            return Json(new { myData = response.This_Object.ToString() });
        }
```

```
public class CheckBoxArray
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Here the List data_json comes empty. However, the data is like:

```
{"data_json":[{"name":"chkBox","value":"1"},{"name":"chkBox","value":"4"},{"name":"chkBox","value":"7"}]}
```

What's the problem here I have that can't get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call the controller action from my Ajax, the value I pass comes null to the controller.

Based on your code, we can find that you'd like to pass a list of `CheckBoxArray` object from ajax client side to controller, and you set request method to `GET`, which would pass the data through query string.

To achieve the requirement and make the data can be bound to action parameter `List<CheckBoxArray> data_json` as expected, you can try to modify the client side code to dynamically generate query string based on your json arrary data, like below.

```
var qparam = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    qparam += "data_json[" + i + "].name=" + data[i].name + "&data_json[" + i + "].value=" + data[i].value + "&";
}

$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateChart","Home")?' + qparam.substring(0, qparam.length - 1),
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        myFunction(result);
        chart.render();
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

For detailed information about model binding and how it works, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#collections

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked like a charm. One more question please, I may need to pass more different parameters to the controller, is it better for me to use a POST method and parse the parameters by ```HttpContext.Request.Form[key]``` ?

Comment: If you'd like to pass more and large data to your controller, yes, you can make HTTP Post request with your data to your endpoint.